# EXCEL- Match and Index Search- Find the value that based on Closest date Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, criteria, closest

I am trying to find a matching B value based on specific value A and closest Date value.

For instance:

Find B, with A = 223 and date is 2017/01/01

Now I have a table with A, B and Date, but the date is not exact match, it will be like

```
A    B   Date
223  5   2017/01/05
223  7   2017/06/08
223  15  2016/11/15
156  54  2016/10/02
146  12  2015/05/06
```

Can I use Match + Index search to set up criteria so that I can find B value based on value A and closest date?

Thank you!!

Comment: What result do you expect with your input of `A  = 223` and date `2017/01/01`? `7`?

Comment: I expect to find B value based on Value A = 223 and date closest to 2017/01/01 from my table

Comment: which in this case would be B = 5